# Copied link with encoded space %20 gets encoded second time. How to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, angular, encoding

There is a link eg. `http://localhost:4200/test/test%20link`, where `%20` is encoded space. When I copy this link and try to open in new tab, the `%20` will switch to `%2025`. How to avoid this issue?

```
openWindow() {
  const link = 'test link';
  window.open(
    `https://window-open-with-angular.stackblitz.io/${link}`,
    'Independent Window',
  this.windowFeatures.join()
);
```

Case scenario: Somebody sents a link, in which is encoded space. When receiver tries to open the link, it crashes due to unwanted encoding.

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/window-open-with-angular-xjy71o?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Your example code does nothing. Please create a reproducible example.

Comment: @DaniloKörber https://stackblitz.com/edit/window-open-with-angular-xjy71o?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer above does not answer the issue.

What was the issue, which caused double encoding? At the top of the appplication was made routing with **Angular Router**, which was encoding url while logging user.

How the problem was solved? A method called [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) was used to solve the problem.

`router.navigate(urlPath) -> router.navigate(decodeURIComponent(urlPath)`

Answer (score 1):

The space character is encoded as `%20` and the `%` character is encoded as `%25`.

The way you get `%2520` is when the url already has a `%20` in it get encoded again to produce `%2520`

If you copy-paste `http://localhost:4200/test/test link` you would only get %20, as wanted.

If you copy-paste `http://localhost:4200/test/test%20link` you would get `%2520`.

Do not encode your link twice when it is already encoded. Send your link with the raw spaces.

Comment: The example in my questions has been updated. The asked issue does not happen anymore if there is no redirections and authorization inside application (which happens inside mine). According to your answer, if you copy `http://localhost:4200/test/test%20link` and open in new tab, which has no redirections or authorizations you will get again `http://localhost:4200/test/test%20link`. Nonetheless, I cannot accept your answer as the most helpful. It provides false and true (depending on the case).